# How do I model a CQL table such that it can be queried by zip_code, or by zip_code and hash?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Hi all I have a cassandra Table containing Hash as Primary key and another column containing List. I want to add another column named Zipcode such that I can query cassandra based on either zipcode or zipcode and hash

Hash | List | zipcode

```
select * from table where zip_code = '12345';
select * from table where zip_code = '12345' && hash='abcd';
```

Is there any way that I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

Recommendation in Cassandra is that you design your data tables based on your access patterns. For example in your case you would like to get results `by zipcode` and `by zipcode and hash`, so ideally you can have two tables like this

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.table1 (
zipcode text,
field1  text,
field2 text,
PRIMARY KEY (zipcode));
```

and

```
 CREATE TABLE keyspace.table2 (
    hashcode text
    zipcode text,
    field1  text,
    field2 text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((hashcode,zipcode)));
```

Then you may be required to redesign your tables based on your data. I recommend you understand `data model design in cassandra` before proceeding further.

`ALLOW FILTERING` construct can be used but its usage depends on how big/small is your data. If you have a very large data then avoid using this construct as it will require complete scan of the database which is quite expensive in terms of resources and time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to design a single table that will satisfy both app queries.

In this example schema, the table is partitioned by zip code with hash as the clustering key:

```
CREATE TABLE table_by_zipcode (
    zipcode int,
    hash text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(zipcode, hash)
)
```

With this design, each zip code can have one or more rows of `hash`. Here's the table with some test data in it:

```
 zipcode | hash | intcol | textcol
---------+------+--------+---------
     123 |  abc |      1 |   alice
     123 |  def |      2 |     bob
     123 |  ghi |      3 |  charli
     456 |  tuv |      5 |  banana
     456 |  xyz |      4 |   apple
```

The table contains two partitions `zipcode = 123` and `zipcode = 456`. The first zip code has three rows (`abc`, `def`, `ghi`) and the second has two rows (`tuv`, `xyz`).

You can query the table using just the partition key (`zipcode`), for example:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM table_by_zipcode WHERE zipcode = 123;

 zipcode | hash | intcol | textcol
---------+------+--------+---------
     123 |  abc |      1 |   alice
     123 |  def |      2 |     bob
     123 |  ghi |      3 |  charli
```

It is also possible to query the table with the partition key `zipcode` and clustering key `hash`, for example:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM table_by_zipcode WHERE zipcode = 123 AND hash = 'abc';

 zipcode | hash | intcol | textcol
---------+------+--------+---------
     123 |  abc |      1 |   alice
```

Cheers!